# WordPress custom fields: types_render_field() not getting output in array format

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using the following code to get the output of `types_render_field()` in an array format.

```
$platforms = types_render_field('platforms-logo', array( 'raw' => true ));
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $platforms );
 echo '</pre>';
```

**getting output:**

http://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/dot_net.png http://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/dot_net-1.png

**Expected Output:**

```
array(
   [0]=> http://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/dot_net.png,
   [1]=> http://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/dot_net-1.png
)
```

Is there any way to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using this solution link https://toolset.com/forums/topic/types_render_field-with-argument-output-raw-still-renders-does-shortcode/

```
$platforms = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-platforms-logo', false);
```

**Note:** The issue was that I was passing the custom field name `platforms-logo` without using the prefix `wpcf-`. When I used this custom field name `wpcf-platforms-logo` with the prefix `wpcf-`. It returns the required array as I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

`"raw"` is used to get data in string so you might remove `raw` parameter or set it `false`.

Something like this :

```
$platforms = types_render_field('platforms-logo', array( 'raw' => false));
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $platforms );
 echo '</pre>';
```

OR

```
$platforms = types_render_field('platforms-logo', array());
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $platforms );
 echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replying.

Comment: I tried your answer but it rendered output not array

Comment: I did it by using this link https://toolset.com/forums/topic/types_render_field-with-argument-output-raw-still-renders-does-shortcode/